# Joint distribution of two normal variables

Tags: normal-distribution

X and Y are independent random variables and they are represented as linear combination of two normal random variables. X=aW+bM and Y=cW+dM How do I compute the joint distribution of W and M? 
Can I rearrange the equations to represent W and M in terms of X and Y and then proceed to find the joint distribution? Or will this approach fail as W and M might be corelated?

Comment: "Can I rearrange the equations to represent W and M in terms of X and Y and then proceed to find the joint distribution?" Definitely the way to go. "Or will this approach fail as W and M might be corelated?" Is this supposed to be a reason why the approach should fail?

Comment: I feel like of W and M are corelated then we cannot rearrange the equations like how we would normally do so while delaing with independent normal random variables. Because for independent random variables we can simply add their individual means and standard deviations but the same cannot be done for normal variables that are corelated

Comment: You can rearrange the relations between random variables, of course, and then deduce from these relations the values of the moments you are interested in. Did you write down W and M in terms of X and Y?

Comment: Yes that's how I proceeded. I wrote down W and M in terms of X and Y and found the variance and covariance of W and M.

Comment: Thus, problem solved?

Comment: Yes :) Thanks for the help!